# DRF caching time out is not setting properly

Tags: django, caching, django-rest-framework

I have cached my Django views using Memcached. I have set TIME_OUT=60*15 but cache expires within 5 minutes.

I'm currently using Django Rest Framework and for caching I use: http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#caching

I have set TIME_OUT in three places.(At first, I set in one place only).
The places where I set cache are:

1. MEMCACHE SETTINGS in settings.py
2. REST_FRAMEWORK_EXTENSIONS = {
      'DEFAULT_CACHE_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT': 60*15
   }
3. In My view,

> ```
>  @cache_response(timeout=60*15, key_func=DefaultListKeyConstructor())
>  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
>     pass
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using **UpdatedAtKeyBit** which used to update cache when a model update is made(mentioned in docs http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#default-key-bits)

```
class UpdatedAtKeyBit(KeyBitBase):
def get_data(self, **kwargs):
    key = 'api_updated_at_timestamp'
    value = cache.get(key, None)
    if not value:
        value = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        cache.set(key, value=value)
    return force_text(value
```

Somehow this was resetting the cache after 5 minutes. When I commented out this, my issue has been solved, though I need to find out a way to update cache when a model is changed.

Comment: hey i have the same problem! the cache only works for some miuntes. did you find an other way?